# Passing value from Modal View to the Tab Bar Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm implementing an iPhone app, which is a Tab Bar based application. At the beginning, I throw up a Modal View, which shows a Login form. If the login is OK, I dismiss this Modal View, and I show the first tab of the Tab Bar Navigation. The problem is that I need to pass the user information from the Modal View to the controller of the Tab Bar.
What I've got so far is:
In my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

tabBarController.delegate = self;
// Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self addTabBarArrow];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//Throw up the Modal View

InicioAppModalViewController *tempView = [[InicioAppModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InicioAppModalView" bundle:nil];
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:tempView animated:true];
[tempView release];
return YES;}
```

In my InicioAppModalViewController I've got 2 functions to throw up a Modal View with the login form by clicking a Navigation button item:

```
- (IBAction)showModalLoginForm:(id)sender {
LoginViewController * loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:loginVC animated:YES];
[loginVC release]; }
```

and then, in this form I've just got some TextFields, and I make a verification if the log in is OK, with the NSURLConnection methods. After that, before of dismissing this Modal View, I would like to send the user information to the Navigation Bar Controller.

How could I implement it? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), which means injecting this information to your controller, what Apple recommends is to use delegation.

So what you have to do is define a property in your tab bar to hold the user information you want to pass then do something like this:

```
[myTabBar new];
[myTabBar setUserInfo:myUserInfo];
```

Comment: I'd rather to use the delegation. I've seen some tutorials online, but anyone with a Modal View and a Tab Bar view distribution.

Comment: @Ruben Changed the wording on my answer now :)

Comment: :) You'are right, "Apple recommends"... could you please check the edits I made in my question? Maybe you could help me even better

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a delegate. In your modal view, have a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
```

Then put this line just before the presentModalViewController:

```
loginVC.delegate = self;
```

You could then implement a method such as collectUserData:(NSDictionary *)information and call it in the loginVC just before you release it like so:

```
[delegate collectUserData:allMyInfoThatIwant];
```